# can I bind to other input attribute besides value attribute in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-directives

I'm new to frontend javascript frameworks. Currently working on a piece of code and I'm curios if it's possible to bind some other input attribute than `value` to `v-model` in VueJS. Here's what I mean:

In my html I have input like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="labels[]" id="label_{{$label->id}}" value="{{$label->id}} v-model="checked">
```

And then later I want checked items to be shown by their names (`$label->name`) but I still need their values to be their ids for the backend.

```
<div v-for="label in checked" >@{{ label }}</div>
```

This of course returns id of the item but I need name. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `true-value` and `false-value`:

```
<input 
 type="checkbox" 
 name="labels[]" 
 id="label_{{$label->id}}" 
 value="{{$label->id}}" 
 v-model="checked"
 true-value="{{$label->name}}"
 false-value="something else" 
 <!-- quote is not required inside true-value, false-value. 
  it will automatically set the type -->
>
```

Excerpt from the [doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Checkbox-1):

> The true-value and false-value attributes don’t affect the input’s value attribute, because browsers don’t include unchecked boxes in form submissions.

Comment: Hi @Bhojendra Nepal, thanks for your answer but this solution for some reason is not working for me.

Comment: when I add `true-value={{$label->name}}` to the input it still binds with the value attribute , therefore picking item's id. I tried putting `false-value={{$label->id}}` underneath but still not working as expected.

Comment: did you try like `this.checked` or `vm.checked`  or `checked` in the template? It should give you the desired result.

Comment: just tried that but failed. do you have working example where your solution passes?

Comment: let's go with the demo :) tried with the quotes but got nothing.

Comment: did you try the demo?

Comment: yeah but still getting ids and I did the same as you :/ I'll upvote your answer since your demo is working and it may help someone else, and I'll see with my code what to do. thanks again :)

Comment: try to debug, and let me know if any helps needed.